# PHP drupal 7 Menu_item won't show when user is nog logged in. _permission

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I think I found it. I just needed to go to permissions in  my configuration and manage it there.

Hi I made this module and all goes well. 
How ever i would like to make it possible for anonymous users to see the Mijn bericht form link in the navigation. And also be able to post a message. How do I do this? I'm quite the noob in Drupal trying to learn it but it isn't as easy as I thought it would be.

Here is my module page:

```
<?php

/*
 * Het module bestand van de module form_bericht.
 *
 */

/*
 *
 * Implementatie van hook_permission.
 * Deze methode gebruik ik om de juiste permissions te geven. Voor het gebruik van de form en het bekijken van de data.
 */

function form_bericht_permission() {
    return array(
        'submit form_bericht' => array(
            'title' => t('submit form_bericht'),
            'description' => t('Submit the form of form_bericht.'),
        ),
        'acess form_bericht submissions' => array(
            'title' => t('acess form_bericht submissions'),
            'description' => t('acess the form_bericht submissions.'),
        ),
    );
}

/*
 * Implementatie van hook_menu()
 */

function form_bericht_menu() {
    $items['form-bericht'] = array(
        'title' => 'Mijn bericht form',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'access arguments' => array('submit form_bericht'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('form_bericht_form'),


    );

     $items['form-bericht-submissions'] = array(
        'title' => 'Mijn bericht form submissions',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'access arguments' => array('acess form_bericht submissions'),
        'page callback' => 'form_bericht_submissions',

    );




    return $items;
}

/*
 * Het eigelijke form van form_feedback
 */

function form_bericht_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['email_auteur'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Uw email adres: '),
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 100,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['bericht'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Uw bericht: '),
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#description' => t('Enter some text...'),
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );




    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Voeg bericht toe.'),
    );
    return $form;
}

/*
 * Validation handler voor de form van de module form_bericht. 
 */

function form_bericht_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
    // Deze if statement wordt gebruikt om te kijken of de email die de persoon heeft meegegeven wel een geldige email is. 
    if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['email_auteur'])) {
        form_set_error('email_auteur', 'Gelieve een geldige email in te voeren');
        return FALSE;
    }
    //check van het bericht zelf.
    return TRUE;
}

/*
 * De submit handler voor onze form.
 * Van de module form_bericht
 * Slaat het bericht op in de databank. In de tabel form_bericht.
 */

function form_bericht_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $nid = db_insert('form_bericht')
            ->fields(array(
                'bericht' => check_plain($form_state['values']['bericht']),
                'email_auteur' => $form_state['values']['email_auteur'],
            ))
            ->execute();

    drupal_set_message(t('Je bericht werd door gestuurd.'));
}

/*
 * View the submissions of the form of form_bericht
 * Berichten worden verwijderd eenmaal ze gelezen zijn. 
 */

function form_bericht_submissions() {
    $results = db_query("SELECT nid, bericht, email_auteur FROM {form_bericht}");
    $header = array();
    $rows = array();
    if (count($results) > 1) {
        $header = array(t('ID'), t('bericht'), t('email_auteur'));
        foreach ($results AS $result) {
            $rows[] = array(
                $result->nid,
                $result->bericht,
                $result->email_auteur,
            );
            db_query("DELETE FROM {form_bericht} WHERE nid=" . $result->nid);
        }
        return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
    }
    drupal_set_message(t("Je hebt geen nieuwe berichten."), 'info');

    return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to control you permission you can use a (look to code, And get what you want only, Since Im get it from my module ..)

```
function moduleName_permission() {
  return array(
    'access download-page content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for the Download units page'),// title on permission page
    )
  );
}

function custom_books_download_menu() {
  $items['download-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Download',
    'page callback' => 'custom_books_download_download_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access download-page content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

this way will return a permission option with name module in admin->people->permission

Also another way you can use

```
'access arguments' => array('access content')
```

this way will give all user permission to access this, for read more about this look to [Access Arguments](https://www.drupal.org/node/553368)

Good Luck